# Scoring multiple output variables with scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am making a regressor which is supposed to output two continuous variables a and b.

The problem is: When you use `cross_val_score` from scikit-learn to evaluate the performance, then you per default get a score across the output variables. I want to get a score for each one. Specifically I want the R2 measure of both a and b.

I haven't been able to find out how to do it yet. Anyone who can help?

Reproducible code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import os
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

 
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


def trainModel():

    # Array to store scores
    nested_scores = np.zeros(NUM_TRIALS)
    
    # Loop for each trial
    
    for i in range(NUM_TRIALS):
    
        # Choose cross-validation inner and outer
        inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
        outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
    
        # Parameter search in outer cross val
        clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=reg, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)
        clf.fit(X_values, y_values)

    
        # Model selection in outer cross val
        nested_score = cross_val_score(clf, X=X_values, y=y_values, cv=outer_cv, scoring='r2')
        nested_scores[i] = nested_score.mean()
        print("nested_score",nested_score)
        
    
    print("R2:",nested_scores)
    

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 6)))

df.columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f']


#PRE-PROCESSING

NUM_COLUMNS = df.shape[1]

X_values = np.array(df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3]])
y_values = np.array(df.iloc[:,[NUM_COLUMNS-2,NUM_COLUMNS-1]])

print("pre-processing done!")

#MODEL TRAINING

NUM_TRIALS = 10

#ELASTIC NET

print("\nELASTIC NET")

p_grid = {"alpha": [0.2, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 3],
          "l1_ratio": [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1]}

reg = ElasticNet(random_state=0)

trainModel()

#NEURAL NETWORK

print("\nNEURAL NETWORK")

p_grid = {"alpha": [0.2, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 3],
          "hidden_layer_sizes": list(range(1,6))}

reg = MLPRegressor(solver='lbfgs', random_state=1)

trainModel()
```

Dummy data:

So basically I have two y-values, and I want the R2 statistic for both of the variables instead of one statistic across the variables. Let me know if you have any questions.

**X_values (the input variables (4))**

[image: X_values]

**y_values (the output variables (2))**

[image: y_values]

**Output for 10 trials with 4-fold cross val for an Elastic Net and Neural Network model. The last line with "R2:" is the average over the folds.**
**

[image: Output]

Comment: Please post a [mcve] using [dummy data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_regression.html).

Comment: I have shown some dummy data now. Let me know if you can help me out.

Comment: The purpose of using dummy data was to make the code **reproducible** (as explicitly suggested in the previous comment), not to post them as screenshots :(

Comment: Ah okay got you, I have pasted my code now, and you can run it.

Comment: In the future, please remove commented-out code and condense gaps (edited). Try to make life for possible respondents easier, not harder.

Comment: Yeah I know, and sorry about that, but I think you are missing the point of this question. It's not a practical one, but a theoretical one. I just want to understand how to operate with individual scoring of each response variable in cross validation with Sklearn..

Comment: I thought you were asking how to actually *implement* this in scikit-learn. If it is a theoretical question and not an implementation one, then it is actually off-topic here and it should be posted at Cross Validated instead; please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).